# jQuery Duplicates of Appended Elements On Click

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to append content to an element depending on the link that is clicked.  If that content already exists, it should not post a duplicate of that content.  The problem I am having is that duplicates are being posted for every link besides the first one clicked.

The links which the content and IDs will be generated from:

```
<a href='#' id="a">a</a>
<a href='#' id="b">b</a>
<a href='#' id="c">c</a>
```

This jQuery script is supposed to check if the ID of the link clicked matches any ID of an li element in the list.  If not, it appends a new li element with the same ID as the link clicked.

```
<ul id="list"></ul>

<script>
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(){
    if($('#list').children('li').attr('id') != $(this).attr('id')) {
        var content = '<li id=' + $(this).attr('id') + '>' + $(this).html() + '</li>';
        $('#list').append(content)
    }
})
</script>
```

The IDs and content are being generated fine but the script only works on the first element clicked, so the output is something like:

```
a
b
b
c
c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try debugging:

## [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dB8GK/)

You will see that `.children().attr()` only returns the first element.

To tackle this issue, you can go over each subelement and see if it equals the clicked `id`:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var clickedId = $(this).attr('id');
    var add = true;
    
    $('li','#list').each(function(){
      if ($(this).attr('id') == clickedId)
      {
           add = false;   
      }
    });
    
    if (add) 
    {
        var content = '<li id=' + $(this).attr('id') + '>' + $(this).html() + '</li>';
        $('#list').append(content)
    }
})
```

If it equals one of the list items, it will not get added.

For future problems: try approaching the problem with simple logic first.

And JavaScript's `alert( )` method is your friend: a great little tool for debugging.

The corresponding jsFiddle can be found here:

## [SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/2nz9K/)

Comment: brilliant! works great. I was using alert() to try to debug but my mind was hung up on $(this) causing the issue, as if it were being cached.  As another answer suggested, it would probably be better to use a different method than matching IDs for a final implementation, but this is great to build off of.

Comment: @flatline_ there is nothing wrong with working with `id`s, just don't copy the exact id, but add something to it like `_li`: `<li id=' + $(this).attr('id') + '_li' + ' >'`

Comment: @flatline_ Also, variables or references to variables are never 'cached' in the middle of an application. So `this` is always referring to what it should be referring. Code is never wrong ;)

Answer (score 0):

First, element `id`s must be unique. Use a class or `data-` attribute instead.

Second, `.attr('whatever')` returns the value for the first item in the collection. A better way would be to try to select the element, then check the length of the collection:

```
if ($('#list > li.' + $(this).attr('id')).length == 0) {
    //doesn't exist!
}
```

Note the selector in my example uses a class for the `li`, not the id.

Comment: On my main code that this question is based off of, classes are already being used, but I was unaware of `data-` until now.  Thanks for pointing that out as I will probably replace this ID method with using the `data-` attribute at some time.